# What will be the output voltage when 9 volt given to LM7812

Tags: voltage-regulator

I'm thinking of using 9 - 25 volt, 1750mA constant current DC input. In the circuit, there is LM7812 after A  component in order to decrease voltage to 12V . My tests shown that when Voltage Is above 12V up to 28V, things look not bad. Output Voltage Is ~12V

But I was wondering that what will be the output voltage if input voltage is less than 12, Ie, 9.9 Volt.

My another question: What will happe if I give voltage from output to input to LM7812? Will it work? will there be flowing current? or will It behave like A  diode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear regulators like the LM7812 have a minimum "dropout voltage" or "headroom"- for the LM78xx family, this is about 2 volts.  This means that the minimum input voltage required for the regulator to work is about 2 volts above the output voltage, so you'll need at least 14 volts into the LM7812 to get 12 volts out.

With 9 volts into an LM7812, I'd expect about7 volts out.  The actual voltage drop across the regulator will vary somewhat with the current drawn from the regulator.

I would expect the regulator to be destroyed by a negative input supply - but consult the apropriate datasheet for full details of the operation of this, or any other IC.

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite as simple as a fixed dropout voltage.

Here is a plot of the dropout characteristics of the [LM340](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm7800.pdf) which is sold as the same part as the LM78xx series. This is a 5V part so imagine the graph extended up to +12 rather than 5.

[image]

Nothing very exciting there, though you can see the drop decreases from 1V at 3V in to about 0.5V at 4.5V in (with zero current draw), and below about 2.75V the part has virtually no output as the internal biasing fails to keep the 'lights on'.  A fixed dropout voltage would have a slope of 1.00 and extend all the way to the 'X' axis.

The quiescent current is well-behaved:

[image]

There was at least one older bipolar regulator (Low dropout = LDO type) that had Iq spiking near dropout as the internal circuit tried to maintain regulation by sucking lots of current through the (very low gain) lateral PNP pass transistor base.

---

Keep in mind that about 3V headroom is required to keep the regulator happy with 1A flowing under all conditions- so the valleys in any input ripple on a 7812 should not go lower than about 15V.

---

Applying a negative voltage to the regulator input relative to the GND pin, if more than a diode drop will cause a lot of current to flow and can easily destroy the regulator.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [7812 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm340.pdf), the drop-out voltage (the difference between Vin and Vout) depends on the load and temperature.  About 2 diode drops at very light loads, and up to 2 V at 1 amp.

[image: Dropout voltage]

Reverse voltage will likely destroy the part. So will Vout > Vin, so a good practice is to use a clamp diode from output to input. (See Fig. 15 in the datasheet.)